Not able to change advertised listener for RedPanda kafka
I have a redpanda kafka container running, where the logs show this
 brokers: {{id: 0, kafka_advertised_listeners: {{PLAINTEXT:{host: 127.0.0.1, port: 29092}}, {OUTSIDE:{host: localhost, port: 9092}}}, rpc_address: {host: 0.0.0.0, port: 33145}, rack: {nullopt}, properties: {cores 1, mem_available 1, disk_available 58}}}}

As can be seen from the docker container logs that it is listening at localhost address.
This is causing me a problem and I want it to listen at host.docker.internal.
Based on redpanda documentation here
https://docs.redpanda.com/current/manage/kubernetes/networking/k-connect-to-redpanda/
I need to have these
redpanda:
  advertised_kafka_api:
    - address: redpanda-0.redpanda.redpanda.svc.cluster.local.
      port: 9093
      name: internal
    - address: redpanda-0.customredpandadomain.local
      port: 31092
      name: default

I also read to translate yaml to Environment config, I need to use upper case. So I am starting my container with below config but it does not seem to take effect
            "REDPANDA_ADVERTISED_KAFKA_API_ADDRESS","host.docker.internal",
            "REDPANDA_ADVERTISED_KAFKA_API_PORT","9092"



Please show your full compose file 2. Why do you think you need host.docker.internal?

